# Getting need struct type but got null exception in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe that I'm trying to cast as a Dataset using a `case class`. I have a requirement where the column `nameSpace` of *struct type* has to have the value `null`.

```scala
case class NameSpace(rid: Int, cid:Int)
case class Act(nameSpace: NameSpace)

val df2 = df.withColumn("nameSpace", lit(null))

df2.as[Act]

// this throws: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from nameSpace#358: need struct type but got null
```

I'm getting the below error message while casting:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from nameSpace#358: need struct type but got null

How to handle this scenario?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want an empty dataset that has a type according to your case classes. This can be achieved by creating an empty scala sequence that is typed:

```scala
import spark.implicits._

case class NameSpace(rid: Int, cid:Int)
case class Act(nameSpace: NameSpace)

val emptyData: Seq[Act] = Seq.empty

val ds = emptyData.toDS
ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Act] = [nameSpace: struct<rid: int, cid: int>]

ds.show
+---------+
|nameSpace|
+---------+
+---------+
```